# Error 404 Page Not Found cuando intento acceder a controlador dentro de carpeta

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, model-view-controller, error404

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña `app` con el `framework CodeIgniter`, pero se me ha presentado un problema al llamar `controladores` que se encuentran en carpetas, he encontrado algunas otras preguntas referentes al tema, pero en ninguna he encontrado la solución.

Lo curioso es que sí puedo llamar los `controladores` que se encuentran en la `raíz` de la carpeta principal de `Controllers` y ejecutan automáticamente el método `index`. No sé qué configuración me hace falta para poder acceder a los `controladores` que se encuentren en carpetas.

Muestro mi configuración actual `(versión CodeIgniter 3.1.10)`:

**routes.php:**

```
//(Este controlador "Login" por default sí funciona, ya que se encuentra 
//en la raíz de la carpeta Controllers)
$route['default_controller'] = 'Login'; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/proyecto';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';(por defecto)
```

**autoload.php:**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```

**Llamada a controlador que funciona:** (Incluí un `.htaccess` para no escribir el `index.php` en la url)

> http://localhost:8080/proyecto/Login

**Lamada a controlador que muestra error 404:**

> http://localhost:8080/proyecto/home/Home

El `controlador` se llama `Home.php` y en su clase `Home`, creí que no había hecho bien algo, y copié ese controlador a la `raíz` y lo llame así:

> http://localhost:8080/proyecto/Home

Y ejecutó correctamente el index, pero desde la carpeta no lo hace, me muestra el `error 404`. Llevo mucho tiempo buscando una solución, pero no encuentro información clara y precisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realicé pruebas cambiando el nombre de las carpetas y funcionó, a lo que encontré fue que `CodeIgniter` es sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo tanto mis controladores lo he estado realizando bien (la primer letra en mayúscula),pero por alguna extraña razón, también la carpeta contenedora debe de tener su primer letra en mayúscula, ejemplo:

> http://localhost:8080/proyecto/Carpeta/Mi_controlador

En este caso anterior, como se puede ver, tanto carpeta y controlador inician con letra mayúscula, y de esta manera sé ejecuta correctamente y no muestra el `error 404`.

Pero, también hice la prueba escribiendo todo en minúscula, tanto en la carpeta como en el controlador, y en la clase del controlador con su inicial en mayúscula, y también funcionó, ejemplo:

> http://localhost:8080/proyecto/carpeta2/mi_controlador
>
> class Mi_controlador extends...

Esto fue lo que solucionó mi problema, por si a alguien más se le llegara a presentar el mismo problema, puede intentar hacer esto.

**Nota:**

En algunos casos puede ser posible que se tenga que crear de nuevo la carpeta o el controlador, según el caso.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la documentación de CodeIgniter-> [Guía de estilo](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer el manual de CI sobre Enabling Query Strings, pero yo prefiero esta forma de enrutado (también en la documentación de CI) explicada muy calarmente en este post:

http://blog.biernacki.ca/2011/12/codeigniter-uri-routing-issue-with-controller-folders/

Ejemplo:

```
$route['carpeta/controlador/(:var1)/(:var2)']  = "carpeta/controlador/index/$1/$2";
```